# Ubuntu for Android and Ubuntu TV

Tags: android, tv

Does someone know when the Distros Ubuntu for Android and Ubuntu TV will get final? I think this would be great products and I no more want to wait for them.

Answer (score 0):

Mark shuuttleworth (owner of canonical- Company behind ubuntu ) has declared in his blog. Development is going on for both products.  He has mentioned in the development of both products will be line up in next 6 months. check out 
[this post.](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1195)

.